# TweetSharp: How to check if you're application is already authorized?

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp, twitterizer

I have gotten my application to authorize, but what I want to know is how do I check to see if my application is already authorized for the current user. So I don't for the user to authorize more than one time?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you save the authorisation key token and secret after you auth the first time. When you start up you check for the saved data and if you find it you know you are authorised (or rather, not to immediately re-auth). You can confirm you are still authorised (access not revoked) by calling the VerifyCredentials method on the TwitterService object. If authorised you get the profile info for the user you are authorised as. If not you should get an error (or null and TwitterService.Response will contain the error details).